# Drop dataframe rows which are missing in an intersection with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
    name    value_1 ... value_n
1    a      11.5    ...  13.2
2    b      11.5    ...  17.9
3    a      10.0    ...  21.3
4    a      9.5     ...  11.1
5    b      10.0    ...  7.2
6    a      10.5    ...  3.0
```

I grouped by name, so I have now two dataframes:

```
    name    value_1 ... value_n
1    a      11.5    ...  13.2
3    a      10.0    ...  21.3
4    a      9.5     ...  11.1
6    a      10.5    ...  3.0

    name    value_1 ... value_n
2    b      11.5    ...  17.9
5    b      10.0    ...  7.2
```

Then, I want to keep only those entries whose `value_1` is in both dataframes. I don't care about the other columns. My attempts:

1. using `isin` -> Does not work, because it requires all the columns to contain the same data
2. Intersection: `pd.merge(group_a, group_b, how='inner', on=['value_1'])`, which kind of works, but results in a dataframe contain the columns of both rows merged, such as `value_n_x` and `value_n_y`, which does not fit my needs

Any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) `subsets` of both `df` like:

```
print group_a
  name  value_1  value_n
1    a     11.5     13.2
3    a     10.0     21.3
3    a     10.0     21.3
4    a      9.5      1.1
6    a     10.5      3.0

print group_b
  name  value_1  value_n
2    b     11.5     17.9
5    b     10.0      7.2

print pd.merge(group_a[['value_1']], group_b[['value_1']], how='inner', on=['value_1'])
   value_1
0     11.5
1     10.0
2     10.0
```

Second solution use  [`numpy.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)  and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
inter = np.intersect1d(group_a['value_1'], group_b['value_1'])
print inter
[ 10.   11.5]

mask1 = group_a['value_1'].isin(inter)
mask2 = group_b['value_1'].isin(inter)

print group_a.loc[mask1]
  name  value_1  value_n
1    a     11.5     13.2
3    a     10.0     21.3
3    a     10.0     21.3

print group_b.loc[mask2]
  name  value_1  value_n
2    b     11.5     17.9
5    b     10.0      7.2
```

Comment: But that does not helps me achieve my main goal, which is droping the rest of the rows from the inicial dataframe. This only changes my approach by giving me only the value_1 row instead of all the rows from the interserction. Any idea?

Comment: I think your aprroach is very nice, only I want improve it by removing unecessary columns.

Comment: sure, and I appreciate it, but I still need to get those results and use them somehow to remove from the initial dataframe those entries which are not present in merge results. For the moment I'm doing it manually, iteraring the results, but it does not seem the pythonic way